# Скрипт обхода ограничения VK API в 1000 человек

Tags: bash, вконтакте, api

Во ВКонтаке, как известно, действует ограничение в тысячу пользователей за один запрос, а ниже приведенный интересный скрипт, который, как пишет автор (https://sohabr.net/habr/post/262053/) настроен на постепенное получение результатов о пользователях, путём уточнения параметров: пола, возраста и т.д.

Прошу подсказать, как можно задействовать этот код? Подставив свой токен, пробовал запускать в Пайтоне (предполагая, что код для него), но безрезультатно.

```
acc_token="abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123"
vk_url="api.vk.com/method/users.search?has_photo=1&count=1000&city=2487&country=1&access_token=$acc_token&fields=photo_max_orig"

for age in {14..80}
do
   echo -n $id " " >>vk.log
   date +"%T" >>vk.log
   mkdir photos/$id
   list=$(curl --silent "$vk_url&age_from=$age&age_to=$age" | jq '.response | .[] | (.uid|tostring) + " " + .photo_max_orig' | \ 
         sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/')
   counter=0
   while read -r line; do
      let counter++
      arr=($line)
      echo -n "$counter." >>vk.log
      photo=${arr[1]}
      filename=${arr[0]}$(echo $photo | sed "s/.*\(\..*\).*$/\1/")
      wget $photo -O photos/$id/$filename
   done <<< "$list"
done
```

Comment: код похож на php или на bash

Comment: код у вас bash, а не python. О чём вопрос? Как использовать скрипт? Как исправить в нём ошибки? Как в него новую функциональность добавить?

Comment: Да, вопрос в том, как использовать скрипт, как его запустить. Раз это bash, пробовал запускать из текстового файла с расширением cmd — но тоже не пошло.

Comment: Спасибо, тег исправил.

Comment: Из ошибок — вроде, необходимо добавить версию в запрос: `&v=5.76`.

Comment: как и в случае любого другого интерпретатора, скрипт можно вызвать, передав путь к нему интерпретатору: `$ интерпретатор путь-к-скрипту`. в вашем случае: `$ bash путь-к-скрипту`